# Getting Invalid field ReplyToken__c for SObject Case: Markup while using tooling api to create an apexpage

Tags: visualforce, apexrest, tooling-api, apexpage

[image: ReplyToken field in case object]

here is the curl and response I am getting while trying to create an apex page

curl --location 'MY_DOMAIN/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexPage' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' 
--data '{
"Markup": "<apex:page standardController="case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">\n<apex:iframe src="https://salesforce.COMPANYDOMAIN.com/SalesforceWidgetProxy?TicketId={!\ncase.ReplyToken__c}\n&accessToken={!$Api.Session_Id}&Instance_Url=https://COMPANY_SF_DOMAIN.com"\nscrolling="true" id="theIframe" height="1200px" width="1100px"/>\n</apex:page>",
"Name": "ORG_NAME",
"MasterLabel": "ORG_NAME"
}
'

--response
[
{
"message": "Invalid field ReplyToken__c for SObject Case: Markup",
"errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
"fields": [
"Markup"
]
}
]

the field exists in my account and has and has proper field level security and accessibility how do I resolve this error

Comment: Just a question: Why the `\n` in front of the "case.ReplyToken__c" (and why after the curly bracket)?